# Build error with android_core

Tags: java, android-core, rosjava, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to install [rosjava](http://docs.rosjava.googlecode.com/hg/rosjava_core/html/index.html) and [android_core](http://docs.rosjava.googlecode.com/hg/android_core/html/index.html) for an Android project that must get data from ROS and send service calls. The rosjava_core installation worked (eventually, there were other problems there that appear to have been resolved), but the android_core build has errors.

So far, I have installed rosjava_core, following the instructions [here](http://docs.rosjava.googlecode.com/hg/rosjava_core/html/installing.html), and built it with the instructions [here](http://docs.rosjava.googlecode.com/hg/rosjava_core/html/building.html). Next, I successfully installed android_core with [these](http://docs.rosjava.googlecode.com/hg/android_core/html/installing.html) instructions and moved on to building rosjava_core with the instructions found [here](http://docs.rosjava.googlecode.com/hg/android_core/html/building.html).

However, the command `./gradlew debug` fails with this output:

```
:android_acm_serial:deployLibs UP-TO-DATE
:android_acm_serial:updateProject
Updated local.properties
Updated file /homes/dzirbel/my_workspace/android_core/android_acm_serial/proguard-project.txt
:android_gingerbread_mr1:deployLibs UP-TO-DATE
:android_gingerbread_mr1:updateProject
Error: The project either has no target set or the target is invalid.
Please provide a --target to the 'android update' command.
:android_gingerbread_mr1:debug
Buildfile: build.xml does not exist!
Build failed

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':android_gingerbread_mr1:debug'.
> Command 'ant' finished with (non-zero) exit value 1.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 2.355 secs
```

(I can post the extended output from `--info` if it's necessary, but I can't discern any additional info from that.)

I've run through the installation several times with a couple different changes, but nothing seems to work. A number of google searches have also yielded no help, and I can't find anyone with a similar error. Am I doing something incorrectly or am I missing some package? I would appreciate any suggestions.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/36947/build-error-with-android_core/) by [zirbinator](https://answers.ros.org/users/2671/zirbinator/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2012-06-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found the solution to this problem, very similar to the one in [this](http://answers.ros.org/question/34109/ant-finished-with-non-zero-exit-value-1/) thread. I simply changed `android_tutorial_camera` from that thread to `android_gingerbread_mr1` and ran `./gradlew debug` again, and it seemed to get past that part. I also had to add every other directory in the android_core folder, but then it built successfully.

Hope this helps someone.

---

Originally posted by [zirbinator](https://answers.ros.org/users/2671/zirbinator/) with karma: 26 on 2012-06-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem was probably that you didn't have the specified target (android-10 in this case) installed. You can of course change the target to one that you have installed, however is should be greater than the one specified in the existing project.properties file.

---

Originally posted by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) with karma: 3838 on 2012-07-02

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1